# Replace a factor column by its counts

Tags: r

I have been trying to find a way to replace an R factor by the count/frequency of it. For example, following data frame produces something like this

```
t <- data.frame(color = c('red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'green'))

  color
1   red
2  blue
3   red
4 green
5   red
6   red
7 green
```

I am interested in replace the factor by its number of occurrences, so it can look like this

```
 color
1    4
2    1
3    4
4    2
5    4
6    4
7    2
```

Because the level `red` has a count of 4, `blue` 1 and `green` 2.

So far, all my attempts seem to be overcomplicated (apply, merge, table,...) and they aren't producing what I need.

Any suggestions on how I could tackle this problem?

Comment: I removed the unnecessary  `as.factor` line because it is done implicitly by `data.frame`

Comment: @RichScriven thanks for the editing and the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tabulate the vector, then expand it using the integer values of the levels.

```
t$color <- with(t, tabulate(color)[color])
t
#   color
# 1     4
# 2     1
# 3     4
# 4     2
# 5     4
# 6     4
# 7     2
```

Another option is to use `ave()` with `length()`.

```
with(t, ave(seq_along(color), color, FUN = length))
# [1] 4 1 4 2 4 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- read.table(text="  color
                1   red
                2  blue
                3   red
                4 green
                5   red
                6   red
                7 green", header=TRUE)

data.frame(x, count=sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) sum(x$color==x$color[i])))
# color count
# 1   red     4
# 2  blue     1
# 3   red     4
# 4 green     2
# 5   red     4
# 6   red     4
# 7 green     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
setDT(t)
t[, color2 := .N, by = color][, .(color = color2)]

   color
1:     4
2:     1
3:     4
4:     2
5:     4
6:     4
7:     2
```